# Angular 4 - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to get some data with Spotify / Musixmatch API in my Angular 4 app but it is not working. I keep getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/album.get?album_id=14250417&apikey=xyz010xyz.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

**JS**

```
  let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log(options)
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'album.get?album_id=' + album_id + '&apikey=' + this.apikey, options)
      .map(res => res.json())
  }
```

[image]

Comment: The headers need to be set on the backend, not frontend...

Comment: @AJT_82 I'm using Spotify API.

Comment: never used it myself, so cannot really help there... have you tried something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41879977

Comment: @AJT_82 Rest of API is working fine getting issue with Authenticate API.

Comment: well in the answer I linked there was how to set the headers... that seems to be the problem here.

Comment: @AJT_82 I've tried some similar APIs getting similar `CORS` issues. I've tried `http://api.musicgraph.com/api`  Getting: ```Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150295/discussion-between-sumit-ridhal-and-ajt-82).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem with browser, typically its a security concern not to allow other requests which may lead to XSS attack easily. 
If only for development I suggest you to install a plugin which will disable in your browser 
[plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

If for production, then you need to configure your API.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to create a file called proxy.conf.json, then put the following code
{
     "/ restapiserver / *": {
         "target": "http: // localhost: 8075",
         "secure": false,
         "changeOrigin": true
     }
}

In the service file, in the url of the rest service, delete the domain and leave the root of the service

private url: string = '/ restapiserver /';

PS: In AngularJS 4

Answer (score -3):

Try this if not yet problem solved by setting header in js.

Add "no access control allow origin" plugin/add-on in chrome.

Yo can find here:[NoAccessControlAllowOriginAddon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)