# Spotify API giving CORS error even after adding auth token to get artist's playlist

Tags: angular, cors, spotify, preflight

Accessing artist's playlist using Spotify's API requires auth token. I am using the method shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879145/get-an-users-playlist-with-spotify-api-how-to-add-access-token-in-http-request) but I am getting following error: "Request header field 0 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Platform: Ubuntu ; Browser: Google Chrome

Update: My Angular service to retrieve artist's playlist.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SpotifyService {

  private searchUrl: string;
  private authToken: string= "My auth token here";

  constructor( private _http: Http ) { }

  get( query: string, type= "artist" ){

    let headers = new Headers([
      { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authToken },
      { 'Accept': 'application/json' }
    ]); // ... Set content type to JSON
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
    this.searchUrl = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + query + "&type=artist&market=US";

    return this._http.get( this.searchUrl, options )
          .map( response=> response.json() );
   }

}
```

Update2: Adding Request and Response Headers:

**Request Headers**

`Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:0,1,2
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:api.spotify.com
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36`

**Response Headers**

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:604800
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Sun, 06 Aug 2017 03:30:56 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=600
Server:nginx
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000;
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff`

Comment: Try to use their SDK if any

Comment: @Microsmsm I do not want to use any SDK or library for my app. Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: maybe @mamsoudi can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP headers are not being passed to your request.

Angular's [Headers](https://angular.io/api/http/Headers#constructor) constructor expects an object, not an array.

Your code should look like:

```
let headers = new Headers({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authToken,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}); // ... Set content type to JSON
```